# How to constantly send a model data with Flask SocketIO

Tags: flask, flask-socketio

I have the following table in my db.

```
class Table(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    number = db.Column(db.String(80), nullable=False)
    chairs = db.Column(db.Integer)
    status = db.Column(
        db.Enum(TableStatusEnum),
        default=TableStatusEnum.free_table,
        nullable=False
    )

    user = db.relationship('User', backref='user_table')
    guests = db.relationship('Guest', backref='guest_table')
```

I need the status field be shown constantly and I need websockets fot that.
I have set it up

```
application = Flask(__name__)
socket = SocketIO(application)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    with application.app_context():
        db.create_all()
        socket.run(application, port=5002)
```

I think I need to loop in Table.query.all() and send the table.status.
I'm just new with this concept and can't find a similar example.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create a background thread to push these updates to your clients. Here is an example:

```py
def background_thread():
    """Example of how to send server generated events to clients."""
    count = 0
    while True:
        socketio.sleep(10)
        count += 1
        socketio.emit('my_response',
                      {'data': 'Server generated event', 'count': count})
```

You can start this background thread with the `start_background_task()` function:

```py
socketio.start_background_task(background_thread)
```

I have a complete example that includes this functionality in the [GitHub repository](https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/Flask-SocketIO/blob/main/example/app.py).

Comment: I'm sorry sir I'm not sure how to use this example to solve the problem. Can you please explain?

Comment: You asked how to send some data constantly. This example shows that. The `socket.emit()` call emits data to clients at regular intervals.